# Deploying Rails App to Heroku: ERROR: relation "todo_lists" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days. Can you guys provide some guidance to fix this and deploy the database to Heroku?

Here is part of my `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "todo_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "completed", default: false
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.bigint "todo_id", null: false
    t.index ["todo_id"], name: "index_todo_items_on_todo_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_todo_items_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "todos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "project_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_todos_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_todos_on_user_id"
  end
```

I'm trying to deploy a new Rails 6 application to Heroku and have done the following:

- `heroku login`
- `heroku create app`
- `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`
- `git push heroku master`
- `heroku run rails db:migrate`

When I run the last command `heroku run rails db:migrate` - I get the following error messages:

NOTE: I created the wrong `todo_list` reference and table at one point, then later removed them, so `todo_lists` does not exist at all on my schema.

**Error message #1**

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
    
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "todo_lists" does not exist
...
/app/db/migrate/20200606053040_create_todo_items.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `ddl_transaction'
...
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1309:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
```

**Error message #2**

```
Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "todo_lists" does not exist
...
/app/db/migrate/20200606053040_create_todo_items.rb:3:in `change'
...
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1002:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1310:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `block in ddl_transaction'
...
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `ddl_transaction'
```

**Error message #3**

```
Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "todo_lists" does not exist
...
/app/db/migrate/20200606053040_create_todo_items.rb:3:in `change'
...
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1002:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1310:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `block in ddl_transaction'
...
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `ddl_transaction'
```

Here is part of my migrations (`rails db:migrate:status`):

```
   up     20200604053157  Create todos
   up     20200606053040  Create todo items
   up     20200606235328  Add completed to todo items
   up     20200606235537  Add completed at to todo items
   up     20200608050430  Remove todo list id from todo items
   up     20200608050957  Drop todo list
   up     20200608051132  Add todo id to todo items
```

20200606053040_create_todo_items.rb

```
class CreateTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :todo_items do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :todo_list, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

20200608050430_remove_todo_list_id_from_todo_items.rb

```
class RemoveTodoListIdFromTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    safety_assured { remove_reference :todo_items, :todo_list, null: false, foreign_key: true }
  end
end
```

20200608050957_drop_todo_list.rb

```
class DropTodoList < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    drop_table :todo_lists
  end
end
```

20200608051132_add_todo_id_to_todo_items.rb

```
class AddTodoIdToTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    add_reference :todo_items, :todo, null: false, index: {algorithm: :concurrently}
  end
end
```

Comment: My complete knowledge Heroku and Rails would be hard presses to fill a thimble. But it is possible you get the error 'relation "todo_lists" does not exist' because you created relation (table)   "todo_items" . According to create_table statement and migration status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed any mention or references of `todo_list` or `todo_lists` from my migration files and committed my code.

Then ran the following:

`heroku run rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I used this command and it worked:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate.
```

I remember a similar issue and I think this was the answer.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby?singlepage=true

Comment: Hey Bchastain - I already ran this command `heroku run rails db:migrate`, which is similar to what you suggested, and it did not work.

Comment: Hey, yes I saw, I seem to remember having the same issue. rake command fixed it if I remember correctly. This is right out of the heroku docs: This indicates that while we could connect to the database, the necessary table wasn’t found. In Rails, you can fix that by running rake db:migrate. To execute this command on Heroku, run it in a one-off dyno like so:

heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3559
Migrating to CreateWidgets (20140707111715)
== 20140707111715 CreateWidgets: migrating ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess the below successful migrations happen in your development environment :

```
   up     20200604053157  Create todos
   up     20200606053040  Create todo items
   up     20200606235328  Add completed to todo items
   up     20200606235537  Add completed at to todo items
   up     20200608050430  Remove todo list id from todo items
   up     20200608050957  Drop todo list
   up     20200608051132  Add todo id to todo items
```

Also the second migration does make a reference to todo_lists :

```
class CreateTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :todo_items do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :todo_list, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But before this second migration making a reference to `todo_lists` I see only one migration which is `20200604053157  Create todos` which probably doesn't do anything with `todo_lists`

So there probably was a migration between the first and the second migrations that was creating the `todo_lists` table. But you have removed this file probably.

It is not a problem in development as this file used to exist and has performed the `todo_lists` table creation. But if you delete this file and ask Your Rails app on Heroku to make a reference to it, it just can't do that anymore.

And then you get an error.

You should never delete any migration file. Because you incrementally perform changes (new tables, destroying tables..) then you should keep everything as is. Or later deployments (and database creations) cannot do what you ask them to do anymore.

Now to fix this: If you still have a copy of the original file, just reinstate it. Otherwise just remove (or edit) any migrations that mentions `todo_lists` whether it is creation or destruction and then reset your database and create it again. (It seems to be a project then I guess it is not a big deal)

It will have no knowledge of the `todo_lists` this time

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Maxence. Although your answer was a bit confusing at first, I ended up figuring it out by removing any references that mentioned `todo_lists`, so I removed it from `20200606053040_create_todo_items.rb`, and removed migration files `20200608050430_remove_todo_list_id_from_todo_items.rb` AND `20200608050957_drop_todo_list.rb`. Could you clean up your answer so I accept it?